How do I show that $ 3^a \geq b^c $ when $ 3\cdot a = b \cdot c $?
Let $ a $, $ b $, and $ c $ be natural numbers. If $ 3\cdot a = b \cdot c $, prove that $ 3^a \geq b^c $.
My try: Solution for the Real Numbers Case.
Consider the analogous problem where $ x $ and $ y $ are real positive variables such that their product equals a constant $ D $, i.e., $ x \cdot y = D $. We aim to determine $ x $ such that $ x^y $ is maximized. Define the function:
$$
f(x) = x^{\frac{D}{x}}.
$$
To find the maximum value of $ f(x) $, we compute its derivative and set it to zero:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( x^{\frac{D}{x}} \right) = 0.
$$
Solving this equation, we find that the maximum occurs when $ x = e $ ($e$ is Euler's number). Therefore, if $ x $, $ y $ and $ z $ are real numbers satisfying $ x \cdot y = e \cdot z $, it follows that:
$$
e^z \geq x^y.
$$
Given that differentiation is not applicable in the domain of natural numbers, what approach would you suggest to address the original problem?

We have $$(3^a)^3=3^{3a}=(3^b)^c,\ (b^c)^3=(b^3)^c$$ Therefore it suffices to show that $3^b\ge b^3.$ The inequality is satisfied for $b=1,2,3.$ For $b\ge 4$ it can be proved by induction or by applying the binomial identity $$3^b=(2+1)^b=\sum_{k=0}^b{b\choose k}2^k>{b\choose 1}2+{b\choose 2}4+{b\choose 3}8\\ ={1\over 3} b[6b+4(b-1)(b-2)]={1\over 3}b(4b^2-6b+8)\\ {1\over 3}b[(b-2)(b-4)+3b^2]\ge b^3$$

Can you please, explain more about the inequalities?

It's essentially the same! By noting that $f(2)=f(4)$, and checking that $f$ is increasing on $[2,e]$ and decreasing on $[e,\infty)$, you know that $f(n)$ is maximised over the positive integers at $n=3$, so we have
$$ b^c = b^{D/b} \leq 3^{D/3} = 3^a $$
where $D=3a$.

The calculus approach is absolutely the cleanest way to prove the result, but it can be proven via pure number theory methods with a bit of effort.
Because 3 is prime, $3a = bc$ implies that either $3|b$ or $3|c$. Both cases will include proving an inequality that is fairly typical number theory homework that I leave as an exercise.
Case 1: $3|b$
If $3|b$, then $b = 3k$ for some natural number $k$. This gives us $3a = 3kc$, i.e. $a = kc$. Then $3^a = 3^{kc} = (3^k)^c$ and $b^c = (3k)^c$, so we just need to prove that $(3^k)^c \geq (3k)^c$, i.e. $3^k \geq 3k$ for all $k$. For $k = 0$ and $k = 1$ this is clearly true (since we have $1 \geq 0$ and $3 \geq 3$ respectively). Then for $k > 1$ we can use induction, with $k = 1$ as the base case.
Case 2: $3|c$
If $3|c$ then $c = 3k$ for some natural $k$, so $3a = 3bk \implies a = bk$. Then $3^a = 3^{bk} = (3^b)^k$ and $b^c = b^{3k} = (b^3)^k$ so we need to prove that $3^b \geq b^3$ for all natural $b$. This time you'll need to manually check that it's true for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$, and then use induction to prove it true for $k \geq 4$.

When $\underline{b=2}:$
$3\cdot a = b\cdot c\implies a=(2\cdot c)/3\implies 3^a = 3^{2\cdot a/3}= (3^{2/3})^a$
But $3^{2/3}=9^{1/3}> 8^{1/3}=2$ hence $3^a>2^c$
If $\underline{b>3}:$
Then taking log on both sides we get;
$a\cdot \log(3)$ and $c\cdot \log(b)$ but $log(x)/x$ is decreasing if $x\ge 3$, because $\left(log(x)/x\right)' = \left(1-log(x)\right)/x^2$ so $$a\cdot \log(3)=a\cdot 3\cdot\frac{\log(3)}{3}=b\cdot c\cdot\frac{\log(3)}{3}\ge b\cdot c\cdot\frac{\log(b)}{b}$$
